# how to skip value in ng-repeat if it is already in another list?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-filter

I have, for example, `person` data with tags like the following:

```
$scope.person.Groups = ['ios']
```

and tags list:

```
$scope.tagsList = ['android', 'ios', 'pm']
```

How could I display only `['android', 'pm']`  with `ng-repeat`?

I tried:

```
<li ng-repeat="tag in tagsList" ng-show="tag != person.Groups">{{tag}}</li>
```

but it didn't work.

How could I only display records that are not in the second array?

Comment: you should use a filter.

Answer (score 0):

**For your context use `.indexOf()`**

First of all you declare the `$scope.person.Groups` is wrong. you go by step by step as follow. first you create the `$scope.person` is a object and create the groups array into that one like the below

```
   $scope.person = {};
   $scope.person.Groups = ['ios'];
   $scope.tagsList = ['android', 'ios', 'pm'];
```

and your html work always

```
<li ng-repeat="tag in tagsList" ng-show="person.Groups.indexOf(tag) == -1">{{tag}}</li>
```

for [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/17209/)

Comment: @Tarun - you are right. you just use indexOf in html part no need to apply filter

Comment: but this is isn't the ideal approach. I think this is a job for a filter! See answer below.

Comment: what if in person i will have array, like [{text: 'ios'},{text: 'android'}] ?

Answer (score 0):

You should use a filter. Here's how you can do it:

**HTML:**

```
<li ng-repeat="tag in tagsList | arrFilter: person.Groups">{{tag}}</li>
```

**Filter:**

```
app.filter('arrFilter', function() {
    return function(collection, person) {
        var output = [];
        angular.forEach(collection, function(item) {
            if(person.indexOf(item) == -1) {
                output.push(item);
            }
        })
        return output;
    }
})
```

Comment: what if in person i will have array, like [{text: 'ios'},{text: 'android'}] ?

Comment: simple, in the filter you just have to iterate over the person array and compare against each iteration's key 'text'. Like this:

angular.forEach(collection, function(item) {
            var flag = 0;
            angular.forEach(person, function(sub_item) {
                if(sub_item.text == item) {
                    flag = 1;
                }
            })
            if(flag == 0) {
                output.push(item);
            }
})

Comment: can you create a plunkr? Need to see where you are going wrong.